# Temporarily changing a Timestamp column so parked rows can be added

Tags: sql, t-sql

for an erroneous situation we've had to park a bunch of DB rows, which we now want to put back into a table. The problem with this is one of the columns, RowVersion, which is of type Timestamp. Inserting the old values does not seem to be possible, so it seems like these would need to be re-generated. I am still researching what the impact would be (seems none/low).

However, I was thinking of a workaround that does keep the original row values intact. My idea was as follows, in 1 locked transaction:

```sql
-- Sample table with only UNIQUEIDENTIFIER Id & TIMESTAMP RowVersion
ALTER TABLE Test
ALTER COLUMN RowVersion VARBINARY(8);

INSERT INTO Test (
    Id,
    RowVersion
)
VALUES (
    'd261ff28-6279-4e81-93f4-825c9ca689bd',
    0x000000000000CF0A
);

ALTER TABLE Test
ALTER COLUMN RowVersion TIMESTAMP;
```

Which results in the error `Cannot alter column 'RowVersion' because it is 'timestamp'.`. Is there any workaround for this? Or to avoid the XY-problem: Is there any ways of inserting rows with a specific row AND keeping the column as a timestamp?

Comment: The point of `rowversion` is that the value changes every time a new operation against the table is performed; with any new rows, or rows effected by the DML statement getting a *new* `rowversion` value. It's not meant to be inserted into, as the database automatically handles the values populated on the column.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, that's what I was afraid of too. Reading our code it seems like a new row version wouldn't break anything, so I guess we can just insert with DEFAULT instead. Was hoping for a 'dirty' hack in order to avoid having to dig through the codebase, but it was a smaller operation that expected :P